# javascript tag trigger - code position on page

Tags: javascript, eventtrigger

i use that tag to alert me when a tag has been shows up

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].onload = function() {
        alert('loaded');
      }
    </script>
    <iframe></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

strange , since this code working :

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].onload = function() {
        alert('loaded');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

why the Js need to under the tag to work?
what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the code in a script tag is executed immediately. And in the first example the iframe doesn't exist at that time. But what you can do is to wrap you code into an onload (for the main page) event. E.g.:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    //your code
}
```

Then it doesn't matter where the code is placed.

Comment: i need to alert immediately when the tag appears in the page. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Iframe tag does not exist at the moment you are trying to access it.
You may check that by simply alerting array length, like

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'));
```

Have you thought about executing your javascript after the page is loaded? You may use some frameworks like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to facilitate crossbrowser issues. Or just put all your javascript code to the very bottom of body.

Comment: i don't want to use jquery since this code is actually API so i can't trust on that.

Comment: Then you may think about putting all the javascript code at the very bottom of body, so that all the page elements are already present by the time it gets executed.